# Beginner in jdbc

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01745: invalid host/bind variable name

```
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:440)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:837)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:445)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:523)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1010)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1315)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3576)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3657)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1350)
at ImageRerive.main(ImageRerive.java:70)
```

Comment: Your question is lacking the main parts: the question itself plus the code.

Comment: Please read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

According to [ORA-01175](http://ora-01745.ora-code.com/)

the problem may be possibly in using Oracle reserved words in you query.

For example:

```
"select from order where date > :date"
```

contains reserved bind parameter 'date'

The list of reserved words can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/ap_keywd.htm)

Can you post your SQL?

Comment: ps= con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO EMPALL VALUES (????)");i want to insert  a iamge                                                                            File  files = null;